# Congratulations Martijn Pieters for reaching a million reputation!

Tags: discussion, reputation, top-users

Today, on 07 December 2022, [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) has reached a million reputation points!

[image: profile for Martijn Pieters at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

I wanted personally thank him for his contribution to [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), where he had written outstanding answers and helped me personally in many cases.

A big thanks to you!